# javascript and jquery book all in one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was always wondering how to use jquery. Should I use it for everything, just some parts, what is a good practice etc.

So I am looking for a jquery book which also explains pure javascript. Some things should probably still be done without jquery. So how to mix jquery with pure js.

Is there any good book which is not mostly only jquery and also not only js, but it explains how to use both in a proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"jQuery: Novice to Ninja" by Earle Castledine is a really cool book. Check it out.

Title:
    jQuery: Novice to Ninja, 2nd Edition 
By:
    Earle Castledine, Craig Sharkie 
Publisher:
    SitePoint

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: FYI: Dead link removed.  @pahnin - For next time, consider including a brief description or summary as well. Because if when links break (like this one) a link only answer become meaningless.

Comment: updated description, you could always google..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any one book for that in particular, but I'd recommend learning javascript first through the tutorials at w3schools or the HeadFirst book (or really any of the many, many things online or in print out there).  It shouldn't take long to get a good basic understanding of how Javascript works, then you will be ready to learn the shortcuts that jQuery provides, by for example going through the tutorials on jQuery's home page: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials .

Comment: I'd recommend http://w3fools.com/ as W3Schools is a how to do it **not** guide rather than the opposite.

Comment: Interesting point of view.  I think w3schools is useful to get started, but they do have a point.  MDC documentation obviously is much more complete and accurate (but for most ppl it would be slow to learn the rudiments from that).

Comment: Well, there are plenty of other websites to learn jQuery. Some of them are Stack Overflow and jQuery.com.

Comment: I'd guess php_guest has long moved on but I just thought I'd thank you for the reference... I've had a look at the Google vids and the Opera standards course.  Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774707) is what you are looking for.